# Correct URL for message to GCM device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The documentation for GCM says an app server should send messages to GCM devices using https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/cloud-messaging/send, yet the sample program (in GcmSender class) uses https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send.

Which one is correct?

I've had a GCM app in the field for a few years which uses the latter URL, and the client side uses the older classes, not the currently documented classes. I guess that means my implementation is C2DM, not GCM, but the above URL inconsistency makes me a tad unsure. Aside from the URL, my app server implementation matches what is documented today, e.g., it uses this format to send messages to GCM devices:

Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "registration_id" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "data" : {
     ...
  },
}

That is also odd - the sample app uses "to", not "registration_id", and my own app uses "registration_ids".

In addition, my app server has never used the "ClientLogin Auth token" that the docs lead me to believe all C2DM apps use. This adds to my confusion over whether my implementation is C2DM or GCM, and hence whether it will stop working on 10/20/2015 or continue working.

Can somebody clarify?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The destination url**

It seems like a classic case of the sample code not keeping up with the latest developments in the API. It happens often enough with Google

https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send is the correct url for sending messages via HTTP. AFAIK https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/cloud-messaging/send, is incorrect.

https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send is for previous versions but still valid.

**to and registration_ids**

The to field is to be used when you want to send a message to a single recipient. The registration_ids field is to be used when you want to send messages for one or more recipients. Thus for sending to just one person both can be used. However the latter expects it's input to be an array.

If you are sending to one recipient at a time it maybe more efficient to use XMPP. XMPP also has the added benefit of being able receive messages from devices.

Comment: Thanks - that clarifies the URL issue. So to summarize, the documented URL is (likely) wrong (should be https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send) but the sample code uses a still valid URL that was introduced for a previous version (of GCM or C2DM?).

That does still leave me wondering whether my implementation is C2DM or GCM, however.

Comment: If you are able to register a device you are using GCM because C2DM no longer accepts new registrations.

Comment: Yes, I am able to register a new device. I guess GCM is compatible still with the old client-side classes (e.g., GCMBaseIntentService, GCMRegistrar, etc.).

Comment: Correct, but those classes are deprecated so you might want to change things up for the next version of your app. THere is a migration guide on https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Yes, it was while starting that migration that I discovered all of this. This should mean that my app server is in no danger of breaking on 10/20, and aside from changing the app server GCM end point URL (not strictly necessary), doesn't need to be changed.